# Can't connect to MongoDB atlas database (Unhandled Promise)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I noticed that if I use the university wifi hotspot I can't connect to the Mongo database. I get a "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning : failed to connect to server" error. However when I use my phone as a hotspot, it works perfectly fine. What could be the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is your university may blocked the mongodb cloud website. Some cases all cloud websites were blocked by university for security purposes. Check [MongoDB Atlas](https://cloud.mongodb.com/user?nds=true&_ga=2.8442806.281985710.1551803358-2058252401.1540791458#/atlas/login) if you able to access the link or not in university website. If you are not then it’s blocked by your university.